# What is the entropy of the cosmological horizon?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, entropy

The Bekenstein-Hawking entropy for a black hole horizon is
$S_{BH}=\frac{c^3 A}{4Gℏ}$.

Is there a similar expression for the cosmological horizon?

Comment: As a general meta comment on this topic, it's not really clear what should be the general definition of a horizon, or how one should interpret this type of relation. A useful third example to consider is the horizon of a Rindler observer, which is purely observer-dependent.

Comment: On arxiv I found various papers explaining that the Rindler horizon has the same entropy as a black hole horizon.

Comment: The issue of defining a general horizon is not important here; the question is about a specific one: the cosmological horizon.

Comment: AFAIK, the entropy associated to the cosmological horizon is still debated.  About the Rindler horizon (in Minkowski spacetime), the problem with it is it has an infinite area.